# How can I get the jobs url from my search on indeed.com in visual basic

Tags: windows, vb.net

I have tried to get links from a search.

I first tried this...

```
Private Sub GetDocumentLinks()
    Try
        If (WebBrowser1.Document IsNot Nothing) Then
            With WebBrowser1.Document
                For Each Items As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
                    'lstLinks.Items.Add(Items.GetAttribute("HREF").ToString())
                Next
            End With
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Info")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have written a new code to search for links with an request. Getting the links is not the issue, redirected is. The strange this is... When I m copy the link in to my browser right page is displayed. Soo why doesn't work that in my request? I have try to limit the redirect, but when there are more redirects, it returns with error.

```
Public Sub ParsingIndeed()
        Dim IntNextpage As Integer = 0

        Do While urlNavigate <> ""
            Dim document As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
            Dim myHttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(urlNavigate), HttpWebRequest)
            myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compat ble; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"

            Dim streamRead = New StreamReader(CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
            Dim res As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            document.Load(res.GetResponseStream(), True)

            Dim node As HtmlNode = document.GetElementbyId("resultsCol") 'id="resultsCol zoeken op indeed.com

            Dim TList As New ArrayList

            For Each noteA As HtmlNode In node.SelectNodes("//a[@onclick]") '("//a[@Data-tn-element]")

                Dim findstring = noteA.Attributes("onclick").Value

                If InStr(findstring, "setRefineByCookie([&#039;radius") <> 0 Then
                    Dim href = noteA.Attributes("href").Value
                    'MsgBox(href)
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(href) Then TList.Add("http://be.indeed.com" & href)
                End If
            Next
            ReDim Preserve StrLinkArray(0)
            ConvertArraylistToString(TList, StrLinkArray)
            ArraySplitOnSpacesAndFiterEmpty(StrLinkArray)
            RemoveDuplicatesArray(StrLinkArray) 'dit zijn alle linken die we gevonden hebben

            For Each noteA As HtmlNode In node.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")

                Dim href = noteA.Attributes("href").Value

                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(href) Then TList.Add("http://be.indeed.com" & href)
            Next
            ReDim Preserve StrUrlVolgende(0)
            ConvertArraylistToString(TList, StrUrlVolgende)
            ArraySplitOnSpacesAndFiterEmpty(StrUrlVolgende)
            RemoveDuplicatesArray(StrUrlVolgende)

            IntNextpage = IntNextpage + 10
            FilterUsefullStringsArray(StrUrlVolgende, "start=" & IntNextpage)

            If StrUrlVolgende.Length <> 0 Then
                urlNavigate = StrUrlVolgende(0)
            Else
                urlNavigate = ""
            End If

            For intteller As Integer = 0 To UBound(StrLinkArray)

                Try

                    document = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
                    myHttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(StrLinkArray(intteller).ToString), HttpWebRequest)

                    myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compat ble; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"

                    streamRead = New StreamReader(CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)

                    res = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

                    document.Load(res.GetResponseStream(), True)

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                End Try
            Next
        Loop
end sub
```

Comment: Since you're consuming what appears to be a rest api, wouldn't you be better to use something like HTTPClient to make your request rather than a webbrowser?

Comment: Yes, I have coded that works but I am getting a lot of errors.

Comment: 1/ Request was aborde. Could not creat ssl/tls sucure channel
2/The underlaying connection was closed: an unexpected error occurred on a send
3/ a genneric error occrurred in gdi+
4/The remote server return an error: 404 not found

I get those errors by searching my first get it links. Those contain pdf files and so one. So I am looking now to optimize my search to get proper links.

https://opensource.indeedeng.io/api-documentation/docs/job-search/#requirements

The site has a web api. I trying that, but it isn't simple for me because all the examples I found is c... not vb.

Comment: Maybe either update your question with the api requests or ask a new one.  Understand the examples might be in C, (there are plenty of services out their that will do a conversion for you).  Once we know whats happening with the api requests you're making we might be better able to help